# How to use a CLI argument after subcommand with the structopt crate?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, structopt

For example, running my application with

```
./app --foo=bar get
```

works well, but

```
./app get --foo=bar
```

Produces an error:

```
error: Found argument '--foo' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    app --foo <foo> get
```

Code:

```
use structopt::*;

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "app")]
struct CliArgs {
    #[structopt(long)]
    foo: String,
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    cmd: Cmd,
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
enum Cmd {
    Get,
    Set,
}

fn main() {
    let args = CliArgs::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

Dependencies:

```
structopt = { version = "0.3", features = [ "paw" ] }
paw = "1.0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [issue 237](https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/issues/237), there is a `global` parameter. Unexpectedly, it is not mentioned in the documentation.

With `global = true` it works well:

```
use structopt::*;

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "cli")]
struct CliArgs {
    #[structopt(
        long,
        global = true,
        default_value = "")]
    foo: String,
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    cmd: Cmd,
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
enum Cmd {
    Get,
    Set,
}

fn main() {
    let args = CliArgs::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

Note that the global argument must be optional or have a default value.

Comment: `global` is not mentioned in the documentation because it is a clap feature. But it is documented that `#[structopt(...)]` supports clap methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide another struct for each command enum variant that has arguments:

```
use structopt::*; // 0.3.8

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
struct CliArgs {
    #[structopt(subcommand)]
    cmd: Cmd,
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
enum Cmd {
    Get(GetArgs),
    Set,
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
struct GetArgs {
    #[structopt(long)]
    foo: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = CliArgs::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

```
./target/debug/example get --foo=1
CliArgs { cmd: Get(GetArgs { foo: "1" }) }
```